# Количество счастливых чисел

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Ну вообще не понимаю как решить данную задачу (наверное она на метод *включения-исключения*).

Условие очень просто : **Найти количество натуральных чисел до 10^N с суммой цифр меньших равных 22 и делящихся на 22**. Ну давайте такие числа назовём счастливыми :P

Может есть какая то закономерность? Ну число делится на 22 если последняя цифра *{0,2,4,6,8}* и сумма цифр на нечетных местах равная сумме на четных.

А да еще числа до 10^18 тобеш N = 18, Час 1 cекунда, может ето что то разрулит :(

Ну и еще примерчик:

```
N = 2 
Ответ: 4  =>  { 22,44,66,88 }
```

Comment: Обычное разложение на слагаемые, перебор всех комбинаций, плюс три простейшие проверки.

Comment: в чем проблема проверки по циклу каждого числа?

Comment: TLE по времени не проходит :(

Comment: *N = 2 
Ответ: 4* А ноль типа уже и не число...

Comment: Ну там только натуральные числа

Comment: "сумма цифр на нечетных местах равная сумме на четных" - это для третьего класса. В четвертом уже проходят правильный признак делимости на 11.

Comment: "проверки по циклу каждого числа" - прибавляйте в цикле по 22.Тогда делимость проверять не надо.

Comment: *там только натуральные числа* Ноль в половине случаев считается входящим во множество натуральных. Если в данном случае он не входит,это надо было бы оговорить... но, с другой стороны, а не пофиг?

Comment: Кроме того, большие диапазоны можно пропускать. Например, 994000 - пока до миллиона не дойдем, ни одно число не подойдет.

Comment: ну ето чтото вроде (10^18 / 22) проверок не так ли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно идти с другого конца.

Т.е. не генерировать числа, а пересчитать возможные расклады цифр, составляющих нужные числа.

Приведу пример для чисел до 10000 и одной произвольно выбранной суммы:

Для суммы цифр `3(mod 11)`, т.е. 3 и 14, возможны 9 вариантов комбинаций первой и третьей цифры (`S14: (95 86 77 68 59)   S3: (30 21 12 03)`) и 4 варианта комбинаций второй и четвёртой цифры (`S14: (86 58)  S3: (30 12)`).

Сумме цифр в пределах 22 удовлетворяют чередующиеся комбинации,выбранные из `S3/S3, S3/S14 и S14/S3`, но не `S14/S14`, так что получается `5x2+4x2+4x2= 26` чисел, делящихся на 22, суммы чередующихся цифр которых равны 3 или 14, и сумма цифр не превосходит 22 (пример - `5390=22*245`)

Comment: То Бишь воспользоваться комбинаторикой - 1-я цифра может быть такая, 2-я такая и тогда за правилом умножения? Приведите пожалуйста еще примерчик для числа 22 если не сложно.

Comment: Примерчик я уже привел, код писать не буду. 22 на два слагаемых не разложить, минимум 3. Нужно заполнить таблицу количеством разложений чисел до 22 на слагаемые в пределах 0..9 и скомбинировать их.

Comment: А откуда именно 3 и 14? что это за волшебные числа?

Comment: @Mikhailo Они не волшебные, я выбрал произвольно одну из возможных сумм: 3 для демонстрации, а 14===3 по модулю 11.

Answer (score 1):

Ясно, что число меньше `10^N` имеет количество цифр не больше `N`

Вам не нужно заморачиваться с большими числами. Тем более, что никуда не поместите эти числа, если допустим `N>20`

Обьявите количество чисел удовлетворяющих задаче  `unsigned answer = 0;`
Создайте массив    `unsigned number[N]  = {0};` нулей.

И в цикле, пока не достигнете начала массива прибавляйте последним двум элементам `2`, остаток от `10` записываем, а целую часть  прибавляем к предыдущему элементу , пока он меньше чем 10(ну как на бумаге суммируете число и 22)

Проверяете, если сумма  элементов меньше 22, то `++answer`

Когда первый элемент массива перестанет быть однозначным числом, `answer` будет ваш ответ.

P.S. С таким альгоритмом ваш код будет работать очень быстро даже при трехзначном значении `N`. А если вам знаком `std::valarray`, то задача решится проще и быстрее, поскольку он оптимизирован именно для числовых методов

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но ваш алгоритм вроде как мало чем отличается от наивного, и сложность такая же log(n), где n = 10^N. А наивный алгоритм при 10^9 уже выполняется >5 секунд [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/jFz8sk)

Comment: Ну ваш алгоритм верен но как же упоминал ранее сложность не та :(

Comment: @Beaver Feller, если вы не понели, это значит я плохо обьяснил, и всего лишь...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Я тоже не уловил, чем это отличается от `22+22=44;44+22=66;66+22=88;88+22=110;...`  с использованием десятичных цифр, каждая в своей ячейке массива, как мы складываем на бумаге.

Comment: @MBo, я уже сказал: если это сделать, например, до двадцатизначных чисел, то  никуда не поместите эти числа  во первых , а во вторых вам каждый раз придется применить к числу функцию, отделяющую цифры от числа, чтобы потом считать сумму и сравнивать с 22, а  я предлогаю просто работать с массивом однозначных чисел размера  20, а суммировать  элементы такого массива  весьма тривиально и быстро...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Ну 10^18 вмещается в 64 бита, но суть не в этом. Алгоритм линейно зависит от верхнего предела. 10^9-10^12 посчитать им ещё реально, а вот больше - уже никакого времени не хватит.

Comment: @MBo, благодарю за замечание

Comment: @GGO Что такое "Час 1 cекунда" в оригинальном посте, расшифруйте....

Comment: Ну это ограничения по времени на задачу :)